# Use knife to create a new recipe in a cookbook

Tags: chef-infra, knife

I've used knife solo to create a new folder and a cookbook with a default recipe using a custom template defined by .chef/knife.rb. My question is what command do I use for knife to create new recipes with that template instead of using cp?

Something like `knife cookbook addrecipe somerecipe`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

once you have the cookbook created, then there will be recipe folder inside the cookbook . you can go on writing as many recipes as you want inside the recipes folder. AFAIK, `knife cookbook` does not provide any option for creating a new recipe. check `knife cookbook --help`

Answer (score 7):

You can use chef rather than knife for recipe creation.

```
chef generate recipe cookbooks/test_cookbook new_recipe

Compiling Cookbooks...Recipe: code_generator::recipe[...]    
- create new file cookbooks/test_cookbook new_recipe.rb    
- update content in file cookbooks/test_cookbook new_recipe.rb from none to 8602b0    (diff output suppressed by config)
```

Comment: This come with the default Chef.

Answer (score -2):

knife cookbook create some-recipe -o ./recipe-dir  (usually cookbooks)

Comment: Can you please elaborate?

Comment: Sure.  I ran this to get ready to use it with Vagrant.  When you run the command, it will initialize a number of files in directory "recipe-dir/some-recipe".  You can use those files as a basis for completing your actual recipe.  If you want actual recipes to do something you can go to https://github.com/opscode-cookbooks.